# google cloud functions: downloading a file to the root directory python 3.9

Tags: google-cloud-functions, filesystems

I have a file I need to get into the Google Cloud Function's directory for a multi-step problem. [Matplotlib: Custom fonts in cloud functions using Python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548074/matplotlib-custom-fonts-in-cloud-functions-using-python-3-9/69550766#69550766)

I'm not sure how to do it. Do I do it as a function in cloud functions? or use the console terminal for the project? I tried that and looked in the root directory and there was nothing there. I can only change projects and not change to a specific function directory.

Can someone please show me how to put this file https://www.1001freefonts.com/balthazar.font into the function's file system so it can be called during execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a Cloud Function to GCP, you can supply a ZIP file or a directory that contains your source code **and** additional artifacts/files that you may need.

To perform the deployment of the ZIP or directory, you will want to use the `gcloud` command.  A good article on this is [Deploying from Your Local Machine](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem).

The detailed documentation on the CLI can be found at [gcloud functions deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

In your example, you could create a directory that contains your source **and** your font file and both will be present in the context of the Cloud Function.  I believe that if you want to reference the files, you will want to use the local current directory in your code.  For example, instead of coding `/myfontfile.font` you might code `./myfontfile.font`.

Here are some references to this technique:

- [Cloud Functions: how to upload additional file for use in code?](https://newbedev.com/cloud-functions-how-to-upload-additional-file-for-use-in-code)